# What does this error "invalid opcode 0xfd" mean?

Tags: evm, invalid-opcode

I found an error message, 'invalid opcode 0xfd'. What does this mean?

I googled, and found just one result [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Quote: "I the invalid opcode 0xfd is never hit
(Some compilers encode safety properties using 0xfd)"

Answer (score 5):

`0xfd` is the `REVERT` opcode as described in the [EIP140](https://github.com/axic/EIPs/blob/5051d0f2977a630a17bbd2e5983491f5b648e0f1/EIPS/eip-140.md).

Things to know:

1. `REVERT` is intended as a "soft throw" that does not consume all the remaining gas. It can also return some data, which could be useful for debugging and user feedback.
2. It is not yet implemented by the EVM; it will be implemented by the first Metropolis fork. This is why it is currently reported as "invalid opcode" when the EVM encounters it.
3. Nonetheless, the Solidity compiler [already implements](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/1661/files) and generates `REVERT`s via the `require()` statement. It is recommended to be used for user input validation. Since the opcode is not yet available, it currently acts just like the old `throw`, but after Metropolis it will implement the new functionality.

Comment: So if you use require() before metropolis fork, it displays 'VM returned with error err="invalid opcode 0xfd"'. But it's worked as expected, so it's not an error. Am I right?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "not an error". Something went wrong if your `require` failed: now it results in the invalid opcode exception; in future it will revert more nicely. In either case the code execution terminates.